# Setting a value in an input Field in Redux Form

Tags: forms, redux, field

i want to create a field using redux form which will contains a "readOnly" box which will have a default value.

So im writing

```
<Field id="current-password" 
       name="current-password" 
       type="text"
       readOnly="readOnly"
       component={inputField}>
       value={userNumber}     
</Field>
```

The userNumber is a prop. 
The inputField is:
i

```
mport React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';


export default field => (
  <div>
    <Input {...field.input} type={field.type}>
      {field.children}
    </Input>
    {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

My layout is like this:
[image]

When my component is render i want it to appear like this. The problem is that the "value" prop is not assigned.
How to solve this?

Comment: Anyone to know how to figure it out??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider mapping state to the ***initialValues*** prop in your form declaration.

Here's how I did it:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        request: state.request,
        initialValues: state.auth,
    };
}
```

A fully documented example is here [Initialize From State](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializeFromState/)